# Populate Model Class in Phalcon

Tags: model, phalcon

I have a model class with manytomany relationship. I'd like to write function which populates the model class. ex. $model->load($id).

I tried this:

```
$model = self::find(
            [
                'conditions' => 'id = ?1',
                'bind' => array(
                        1 => $id
                ),
                'hydration' => Model\Resultset::HYDRATE_ARRAYS
            ]
            );
```

I tried all hydration modes the result does not change. Every time the result is a Resultset class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Model::findFirst()`

Comment: Thank you. Works :)